# associating orders to products

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have an issue trying to associate a particular order with a particular product. I am new to node.js, I want to add a product(be associated and be populated with an order) and be redirected to a page which shows all orders of products i created

created the product and order schema(not too sure about the other schema)...

This is my product model

```
var mongoose= require("mongoose");
var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    brand:String,
    price: Number, 
    image: String,
    description:String,
    featured: Boolean,

 });

module.exports= mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);
```

This Is order model:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var orderSchema= new mongoose.Schema({

_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   products:[
        {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:"Product", required:true
        }
    ]
,
quantity :{type:Number, default:1}
});
module.exports=mongoose.model("Order",orderSchema);
```

I want this models to be associated together using the `mongoose` method, be populated and then appear on a route ("`/order`) for example. I am new to programming and as such the simplest answer would be appreciated.

Comment: So you want your order model to have product details am i right?

Comment: yes please,that is the intention

Comment: So what are you getting now in your route for orders

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small working example using Express.Js, in this example I created 3 models :

```
// Models
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String
 });

var orderSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
  products:[productSchema]
});

const clientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  order: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Order'
  }
})
const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
const Client = mongoose.model('Client', clientSchema);
const Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);
```

My `orderSchema` will embed the products ordered by my clients, I chose to store products as [subdocuments](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) because I will have only few, you could also choose to store [references](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#saving-refs) instead.
**Note**: I'a referencing only one order per Client, you could choose otherwise, and make the order field in the `clientSchema` in an array (`order: [{ /* type...*/}]`)
In my controller I have 2 methods: one to create an order and the other to add a product to the order.

```
// Controller
const createOrder = (userId, productId) => {
  Product.findOne({_id: productId}) // find a product
    .exec()
    .then(product => new Order({products: [product]}).save()) // save the products into the order
    .then(order => Client.findOneAndUpdate({_id: userId}, {$set: {order: order}}).exec())// update the client document with the new order
    .then(client => res.json(client)); // respond with json
    // .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
const addToOrder = (userId, productId) => {
  return Product.findOne({_id: productId}) // find the product
    .exec()
    .then(product => {
      return Client.findOne({_id: userId})//find the client
        .populate({ path: 'order', populate: { path: 'order.products' } })
        .exec() //populate in order to access client.order.products
        .then(client => {
          client.order.products.push(product);
          return client.order.save();
        })
    })
    // .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

I know need two routes: one to render a table with all the available products and one to render a cart with the ordered items.

```
// Get all products
app.get('/products', function(req, res) {
  Product.find({})
    .exec()
    .then(products => res.render('products.ejs', {allProducts: products}))
    .catch(err => res.json({errors: err}));
});

// Order a product
app.get('/products/:productId/order', function(req, res) {
  req.user = {id: ""} /* id of the client, or the logged in user if you're using passeport or some other auth manager */
  Client.findOne({_id: req.user.id})
    .exec()
    .then(client => {
      if(client.order) {
        return addToOrder(client.id, req.params.productId)
          .then(order => res.render('cart.ejs', {order: order}))// render cart with the order
      } else {
        return createOrder(client.id, req.params.productId)
          .then(order => res.json('cart.ejs', {order: order}))
      }
    })
    .catch(err => res.json({errors: err}));
})
```

I need two (rendered by my route handlers):

```
// /views/products.ejs
<div>
      <table>
        <% allProducts.forEach(function(product) { %>
          <tr>
            <th>name</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><%= product.name %></td>
            <td><a href=<%=`/products/${product.id}/order`%>> Order </a> </td>
          <tr>
        <% }) %>
      </table>
    </div>


// views/cart.ejs
<div>
  <table>
    <% order.products.forEach(function(product) { %>
      <tr>
        <th>name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><%= product.name %></td>
      <tr>
    <% }) %>
  </table>
</div>
```

I hope this helps.